# Resolve composer packages cyclic dependencies

Tags: php, package, composer-php

I am building application based on separate composer packages. I have package "user" for authentication, user management and all user things. And i have package "captcha" for management captcha. Captcha requires user because captcha has management that need admin user, roles, permission and other. But i need to enable captcha in user. How can i do that if captcha requires user but not reverse? I need to add in db settings for authentication, registration captcha in captcha tables and if course i need to check captcha enabled by knowing tables of captcha.

Now i simply allow user to require captcha and add migration that adds user captcha settings and check captcha in user requests. Is it normal?

Comment: "Captcha requires user" sounds like the wrong approach. Also, how is this related to Composer? Are you facing any specific problem?

Comment: I have described why. Captcha has management by admin. Models has editor user model. I can't manage anything without admin and i can't put it in user package. About composer i also described. I have separate packages. Did you read my question to the end?

Comment: "How can I do that" - can you be more specific? Is there anything not working when requiring these packages? Even if the dependencies are cyclic, does this cause any **specific** problem? Please edit your question to contain all details

Comment: The question is in the end. Is it normal that i add cyclic dependencies. Really, do you read to the end?) Everything works, but i read that cyclic dependencies is bad practice, but how can i do without it?

Comment: "Is it normal" is a strange question. Why shouldn't that be normal? If you structure your packages like that, if you don't want to decouple users from captcha handling, that can be fine. Do you expect others to list examples of cyclic dependencies, or how shoudl "Is it normal" be answered?